# Java - JTextField - Call function when user press "space bar"

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener

I made some searches and I didn't find how to call a function when the user press the key "space bar", I have this code:

```
edtCodigos.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
            callFunction();
        }
    }
)};
```

Note: I want to avoid the "space", the key will be used just to call the function

Any ideas how can I do it or code samples will be appreciated ;)

Comment: never to use KeyListener for JTextComponents, in this case to use DocumentFilter, tons of code examples here

Comment: Why? What does the function _do_? Are you trying to do filtering or validation? Just seems weird, your explanation. If you want to end the typing and process the field data, a more common approach would be to use an ActionListener and let the Enter key begin the process. Please elaborate a little more, so this doesn't become an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: It's an usability problem.. The users are used to type "space bar" to finish an operation like payment in a cashier..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "The users are used to type "space bar" to finish an operation like payment in a cashier."

Personally, I would just use an `ActionListener` so that the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key triggers the event. It just seems more natural.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestTextField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JTextField field = new JTextField(15);
        field.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Enter Pressed: " + field.getText());
            }
        });
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, field);
    }
}
```

If you want to use <kbd>Space</kbd>, you can bind the key the field using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestTextField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JTextField field = new JTextField(15);
        InputMap imap = field.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
        imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "spaceAction");
        ActionMap amap = field.getActionMap();
        amap.put("spaceAction", new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Space Pressed: " + field.getText());
            }
        });
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, field);
    }
}
```

You could even go as far as using a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) to listen for changes in the underlying document of the text field, and check the last character entered was a space (but this seems like a bit much - Just some info for you to learn the workings for text components :-)

Pick your flavor. I like the first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really appreciate it! Actually I prefer the first answer too... but you know, customers.. You can't go against them... "Customers are always right..." ;)